# Avoid using functions inside if condition - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why should we avoid call functions inside if conditions in functions? For instance:

```
var numberChoice = function(number){
   if (number == 1){
       alert("You have choosen 1");
       nextLevel();
   }

   else if(number == 2){
       alert ("You have choosen 2");
       nextLevel2();
   }

   else{
       alert("Please choose a number within range 1-2");
       guessAgain();
   }
};

var number = prompt("What is your number?");
```

I could possible have missunderstood what's going on. Are you able to give an explanation of it?

```
function example(){
  function a() {} // Okay 
  if (something) {
     function b() {} // Danger! 
  } 
}
```

Haverbeke, Marijn (2014-12-04). Eloquent JavaScript: A Modern Introduction to Programming (Kindle Locations 1168-1169). No Starch Press. Kindle Edition.

Comment: You can call functions inside if condition. Who said that to not to call a function inside an if statement?

Comment: What's telling you not to do that?

Comment: Besides, the given code calls functions inside `if` body, not condition. Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: Probably you are referring to something like async code ?!

Comment: @JordanHendrix: Can you please provide an example of this? I've never heard of this crazy warning.

Comment: Using functions anywhere is acceptable as long as you can justify the use of the call to it.

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood. Creating functions within conditionals probably isn't best practice.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of the warning to not declare functions in a block? The premise of this question is just too vague to give a meaningful answer other than to reject the premise altogether.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply and clarification. I thought it was very strange and couldn't understand why. I'll try find it and come back with references.

Comment: Jonathan Gray - What would you consider is the best practice of my code? Any links you can recommend? Feels like i'm flying around like a paper plane with no direction.

Comment: Exactly what @JonathanGray said. You thought it was a call, but that was function declaration within a block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your function (within if condition) is asynchronous there is no problem.
The functions that you are using is synchronous - meaning your script will finish executing it and return a value first before going to next task - in this case it will work fine.
For asynchronous function (which is executed in parallel to the other lines of instructions), then the results from that function is not returned yet and your script will continue without the right value (returned value) from it - this will cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your two sample there is no issue.

there is no rule that don't allow you to call function in a if condition.

the only point is a warning when you have several if on the same checking :

```
if (number === 1) {
  function1();
}

    if (number === 2 ) {
       function2(); 
}
```

in that case if you don't put return at the end of your function when the function will be called other condition will be evaluate.

better code is using `else` or `switch`

In your case there are no issue.